# ArrayList error indexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, checkbox, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have one `ListView` with `CheckBox`, whenever user pressed the checkbox I'm getting some user information and stored in `ArrayList`. When unchecked the checkbox the user information remove from arraylist.

Now what's the problem is that sometimes it gives error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
```

when unchecked the checkbox and application in unfortunately stops.

Code:

```
if (compoundButton.isChecked()) { 
       arrayList.get(arg0).setStatus(1); 
       barcode = arrayList.get(arg0).getBarcode(); 
       proprice = arrayList.get(arg0).getPrice();
       productname=arrayList.get(arg0).getItemName(); 
       Listbarcode.add(barcode + "," + productname + "," + proprice); 
} else { 
    if (Listbarcode.size() > 0){ 
        Listbarcode.remove(arg0); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you post adapter code?

Comment: Post some relevant codes..

Comment: When you face such kind of issues, make sure you post the code block and also Logcat. Just by explaining in words no one can help you here. So u get downvotes!

Comment: Show some relevant code... you are probably not setting a loop right.

Comment: The error exception is correct. Trust it.

Comment: Please post all relevant code. Use the code format, but edit your main post and put it there. It's very unreadable when all your code is smushed into 1 line.

Comment: on which poin do you get exception? make some Log.v.("projectName","pass 1"); or something to get a point where your app meets the end.

Comment: dynamically add checkbox and barcode detail in listview. sometimes when unchecked the checkbox it give the error arrayoutofbound index error.

Comment: logcat error : http://prntscr.com/84fvpr

Comment: This is not enough to find the problem. I think that you did not share relevant code. You don't even know exactly where you get exception. Put some Log.v in your code and you will see where the problem is.

Comment: You are getting exception somewhere around line 131 in your CustomAdapter.java. There you have a loop which is not set properly.

Comment: give error here in 131 line :  if (Listbarcode.size() > 0)
                                               { Listbarcode.remove(arg0); }

Comment: ok then this is in loop. Can you show it? Show while() or for() loop. what is arg0? It's value is bigger than it should be. And add this loop in your post by edit please.

Comment: arg0 is position of  getView(final int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) method.

Comment: well this position is bigger than array.size(). Put that loop in your post by edit - otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: here is code of checkbox : http://prntscr.com/84g03z

Comment: m not use any loop in my code

Comment: you are not showing enough. As I told you, arg0 is apparently bigger than Listbarcode.size().

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean type variable in your pojo class of which you are making arraylist of like. like 
             `boolean checked;`

Then generate getter setter for the boolean variable.

While checking and  unchecking the checkbox on UI. Check whether the chechbox is checked or not and set the boolean checked value accordingly.